# NextJS webpack config - Exclude files from being compiled

Tags: webpack, next.js, react-native-web

I need some help with **NextJS webpack config**?

I have a mono-repo and share code between **React-Native** and **NextJS**. To split OS-specific code I separated the native and the web code like that:  (`Login.web.tsx` & `Login.native.tsx`)

Example: `/Login/index.tsx`

```js
import React, { lazy, ReactElement, Suspense } from 'react'
import { Platform, View } from 'react-native'

const LoginComponent = lazy(() => (Platform.OS === 'web' ? import('./Login.web') : import('./Login.native')))

const Login = (props: NavigationProp): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<View />}>
      <LoginComponent {...props} />
    </Suspense>
  )
}

export default Login
```

This example code is located in the `ui-screens` project and will be imported into the one and only NextJS page like that

```js
import { Login } from '@monorepo/ui-screens'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Login />
  )
}
```

React-Native deals perfectly with that and loads the correct `Login.native.tsx` page. But the **NextJS webpack compiler** still sees this file `Login.native.tsx` and tries to compile it, which obviously causes errors.

When I change the code of `/Login/index.tsx` like that, for test purposes, my web app runs fine

```js
const LoginComponent = lazy(() => (Platform.OS === 'web' ? import('./Login.web') : import('./Login.web')))
```

How can I make webpack to exclude files that have the `*.native.*` extensions?

Note: I tried `RemovePlugin`:

```js
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins')
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([
  'react-native',
  '@types/react-native',
  '@monorepo/ui-screens'
])
const RemovePlugin = require('remove-files-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = withPlugins([withTM()], {
  enableSvg: true,
  esModule: true,
  images: {
    disableStaticImages: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new RemovePlugin({
      before: {
        include: ['Login.native.tsx']
      }
    })
  ],
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...(config.resolve.alias || {}),
     'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
    }
    config.resolve.extensions = ['.web.js', '.web.jsx', '.web.ts', ...config.resolve.extensions]
    return config
  }
}
```

But it has no effect.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're on the right track I think. I have the damnest time with Webpack, feel your pain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After hours of reading the webpack docs, Github issues and comments, I have finally found a super easy solution called `webpackIgnore`

Just by inserting it into the `import` command, I can tell webpack to literally   ignore the file at compilation time:

```js
const LoginComponent = lazy(
 () => (Platform.OS === 'web' ? 
 import('./Login.web'): 
 import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ './Login.native'))
)
```

I love this elegant solution.

Now I only have to tell my Typescript compiler to NOT delete this line.

Comment: Well done. I'm looking for a pure nextjs webpack config to just ignore the native and take only web.js or other js files. Can't seem to find one.

Comment: Does anyone know why `config.resolve.extensions` have no effect in NextJS webpack config??

Comment: I believe packages such as `react-native-svg` relies on file extension splitting

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I seem to have been able to get around it by moving the affected files into the public folder.

In my case I had two files which contained functions being used by many different components. In the components, the function were called using useEffect, so there was no issue until I tried to build the project. Moving the files into the public folder and changing some references allowed my project to build successfully and keep working.

[Next.js only prerenders files in the pages folder.](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error)